# How are two items being added to this observable list?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-8

I'm coming from a Swing background and trying to pick up JavaFx.

This `ObservableList` is being filled with strings, and added to a `ListView`.

When I add an item to the observable list in the same thread, everything works fine.

However, when I try to add an item to the observable list from a **different thread**, the items are being added twice.  For the life of me, I cannot figure out why.  Debug statements show the Thread is in fact only executing once.

Here's a fully working example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class FeedPanelViewer extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    String greeting = "<html><body><p><strong>hi ya'll</strong></p></body></html>";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Matthew", "Hannah", "Stephan", "Denise");

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>(names);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(listView));
        stage.show();

        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
                return new HtmlFormatCell();
            }
        });

        // This thread is definitely only adding items once
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                System.out.println("Got here");
                names.add(greeting);
                names.add("andrew");
            });
        }).start();
    }

    public class HtmlFormatCell extends ListCell<String> {

        public HtmlFormatCell() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (item != null) {
                if (item.contains("<p>")) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        WebView web = new WebView();
                        WebEngine engine = web.getEngine();
                        engine.loadContent(item);
                        web.setPrefHeight(50);
                        web.setPrefWidth(300);
                        web.autosize();
                        setText("");
                        setGraphic(web);
                    });
                } else {
                    setText(item == null ? "" : "-" + item);
                    setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
                    if (isSelected()) {
                        setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out the two lines `new Thread(() -> {` and `}).start();`, this is what I see:

[image: desired screen shot]

And with the `Thread` wrapped around the addition of the two list elements, I'm seeing this, which is rendering the cells twice, even though the thread is only executing once:

[image: undesired screen shot]

Can anyone help point out what is going on?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `updateItem`, you should have an `else` branch for when the item is empty (i.e. when `item == null`, or, better yet, when `empty` is true) and clear the cell, i.e. `setText(null); setGraphic(null);`.

Your `updateItem` method should something like this

```
if(!empty) {
    // populate the cell with graphic and/or text
} else {
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(null);
}
```

In your example, it is likely that the last two cells are *empty*, but have not been cleared.

**Note 1:** The way ListView allocates and populates cells is (seemingly) unpredictable and it can do a lot of redundant item updates.

**Note 2:** This does not by itself explain the difference in behavior you get with your two versions. My guess is that without the Thread wrapper, the call gets executed before the ListView's first layout pass, while with the Thread wrapper, it layouts the initial items and then updates the layout for the added items. This, together with the previous note, could explain the difference in the results.

**Note 3:** In `updateItem`, you don't have to wrap your calls in `Platform.runLater`, since `updateItem` is already executed on the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: Wow-- that is definitely the solution.  Thanks very much!  Since empty cells aren't being explicitly set in the code, it would've taken me forever to figure this out.